# Magnetic Hover Interaction with Cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

Is there a way to achieve the effect of mouse hover like on the website below:

https://studiomaertens.com/about

if you hover on the Work or About link, there is a magnetic effect on it as well as the cursor automatically scales and positions itself in the center with the link,

So far I've managed to combine two different examples together, the magnetic effect works but the cursor doesn't align properly with the icons

https://codepen.io/pen/?template=mdPmPbK

```
<main>
    <div>
    <button class="cerchio" >
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    </div>
    <button>
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</main>


<div class="cursor cursor--large"></div>
<div class="cursor cursor--small"></div>
```

```
var cerchio = document.querySelectorAll('.cerchio');

cerchio.forEach(function(elem){
  $(document).on('mousemove touch', function(e){
    magnetize(elem, e);
  });
})

function magnetize(el, e){
  var mX = e.pageX,
      mY = e.pageY;
  const item = $(el);
  
  const customDist = item.data('dist') * 20 || 120;
  const centerX = item.offset().left + (item.width()/2);
  const centerY = item.offset().top + (item.height()/2);
  
  var deltaX = Math.floor((centerX - mX)) * -0.45;
  var deltaY = Math.floor((centerY - mY)) * -0.45;
  
  var distance = calculateDistance(item, mX, mY);
    
  if(distance < customDist){
    TweenMax.to(item, 0.5, {y: deltaY, x: deltaX, scale:1.1});
    item.addClass('magnet');
  }
  else {
    TweenMax.to(item, 0.6, {y: 0, x: 0, scale:1});
    item.removeClass('magnet');
  }
}

function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
  return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
}

/*- MOUSE STICKY -*/
function lerp(a, b, n) {
    return (1 - n) * a + n * b
}

// Inizio Cursor
class Cursor {
  constructor() {
    this.bind()
    //seleziono la classe del cursore
    this.cursor = document.querySelector('.js-cursor')
    
    this.mouseCurrent = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
    
    this.mouseLast = {
      x: this.mouseCurrent.x,
      y: this.mouseCurrent.y
    }
    
    this.rAF = undefined
  }
  
  bind() {
    ['getMousePosition', 'run'].forEach((fn) => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this))
  }
  
  getMousePosition(e) {
    this.mouseCurrent = {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY
    }
  }
  
  run() {
    this.mouseLast.x = lerp(this.mouseLast.x, this.mouseCurrent.x, 0.2)
    this.mouseLast.y = lerp(this.mouseLast.y, this.mouseCurrent.y, 0.2)
    
    this.mouseLast.x = Math.floor(this.mouseLast.x * 100) / 100
    this.mouseLast.y = Math.floor(this.mouseLast.y * 100) / 100
    
    this.cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${this.mouseLast.x}px, ${this.mouseLast.y}px, 0)`
    
    this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.run)
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame() {
    this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.run)
  }
  
  addEvents() {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.getMousePosition, false)
  }
  
  on() {
    this.addEvents()
    
    this.requestAnimationFrame()
  }
  
  init() {
    this.on()
  }
}

const cursor = new Cursor()

cursor.init();
```

Might there be a way to make a similar effect on the Studiomaertens website above?

Kindly let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To align the cursor in center use

```
.cursor{
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I added the css but does not seem to have any change on it,

might there be a specific place i need to add it on?